# Selecting a single (random) row for an SQL join

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've got an sql query that selects data from several tables, but I only want to match a single(randomly selected) row from another table.

Easier to show some code, I guess ;)

Table K is (k_id, selected)
Table C is (c_id, image)
Table S is (c_id, date)
Table M is (c_id, k_id, score)

All ID-columns are primary keys, with appropriate FK constraints.

What I want, in english, is for eack row in K that has selected = 1 to get a random row from C where there exists a row in M with (K_id, C_id), where the score is higher than a given value, and where c.image is not null and there is a row in s with c_id

Something like:

```
select k.k_id, c.c_id, m.score
 from k,c,m,s
where k.selected = 1
  and m.score > some_value
  and m.k_id = k.k_id
  and m.c_id = c.c_id
  and c.image is not null
  and s.c_id = c.c_id;
```

The only problem is this returns all the rows in C that match the criteria - I only want one...

I can see how to do it using PL/SQL to select all relevent rows into a collection and then select a random one, but I'm stuck as to how to select a random one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with analytics:

```
SELECT k_id, c_id, score
  FROM (SELECT k.k_id, c.c_id, m.score, 
               row_number() over(PARTITION BY k.k_id ORDER BY NULL) rk
           FROM k, c, m, s
          WHERE k.selected = 1
            AND m.score > some_value
            AND m.k_id = k.k_id
            AND m.c_id = c.c_id
            AND c.image IS NOT NULL
            AND s.c_id = c.c_id)
 WHERE rk = 1
```

This will select one row that satisfies your criteria per k_id. This will likely select the same set of rows if you run the query several times. If you want more randomness (each run produces a different set of rows), you would replace `ORDER BY NULL` by `ORDER BY dbms_random.value`

Comment: ORDER BY NULL will probably not generate a random order. Inpredictable, yes, but not random. The rows will (most likely) be returned in the order they're stored in the index or wherever they're read from, which might or might not be good enough for the OP.

Comment: @erikkallen> I agree, I updated my answer with a way to add randomness to impredictability :>

Comment: Perfect! - looks like PARTITION BY was the key. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the 'order by dbms_random.random' instruction with your query.

i.e.:

```
SELECT column FROM
  (
    SELECT column FROM table
    ORDER BY dbms_random.value
  )
WHERE rownum = 1
```

References:
http://awads.net/wp/2005/08/09/order-by-no-order/
http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too familiar with oracle SQL, but try using LIMIT random(), if there is such a function available.

Comment: Oracle SQL does not support the LIMIT keyword.

Comment: It does, just call it rownum ... and rownum <= x is limit x